SQL Functions in databricks
I want to create a function in SQL that returns yes if it's the first day of the month, else no. Below doesn't work.
create temporary function newmonth() 
  returns string(20) 
  deterministic 
      BEGIN
      IF day(date) <> '01' then
      return ('NO')
      else
      return ('YES')
  END IF; 

Can anyone help me out?

BEGIN and IF/END IF are  for stored procedures not SQL functions. Also DAY returns INTEGER. The function body should be just a RETURN statement, like RETURN CASE WHEN DAY(DATE)=1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END

First create your Databricks SQL function
%sql
create temporary function newmonth() 
  returns string 
  return case 
  when day(current_date) <> '01' 
    then "NO"
    else "YES"
    end

Then call it.
%sql
SELECT newmonth() AS newmonth;

Since we are in October, we will get "NO" as a result.
you shoudl ideally create a function to accept a date and return the flag. Then when calling, it call it using the current_date.

Here you are using string(20) datatype in place of that you can use varchar(20) datatype and also in place of day(date) you can try using day(current_date). Finally end the BEGIN...END block with END statement because BEGIN...END block should end with END statement.

Kindly let me know the suggestion which I have provided is useful or not .
